# W509Certificate2 reference missing

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get a Google Drive API working with the delegated service account method as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation). The problem I have is with this line where I'm supposed to create a X509Certificate object:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret",
            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

However, the compiler tells me, "The type or namespace name X509Certificate2 could not be found." I'm using `System.Security.Cryptograpy` and `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates`, which according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx), should include the X509Certificate2 class. The problem is, mine doesn't for some reason. It has X509Certificate, but that doesn't work with the example above. I have tried .net v4.5 and 4.

Comment: Is your project targeting .NET 4.5?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I should have included that to begin with.

Comment: I created a new console app, typed `X509Certificate2` and pressed ctrl+. and it resolved fine. Can you check the version of those dlls you added by expanding references and checking their properties?

Comment: Actually, try removing them. You shouldn't need them as the X509Certificate2 exists in `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` in `System.dll` version 4.0.0.0

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how my references got messed up, but I just created a new project from scratch and now it works. What's more is I can see the class in the object browser, where I couldn't before. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! I'll put it into the answer in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 5):

`X509Certificate2` exists in `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` in `System.dll` so other references may be interfering with it, or there could be a problem with dlls being the wrong version.